# Запись output в файл. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, powershell

Необходимо вывести в файл, все что python обычно выводит в консоль, будь то исключения, ошибки или простой вывод.
Был опробован метод `add-content` в powershell, после чего попытка написания скрипта, но для запуска скрипта необходима либо подпись скрипта, либо понижение уровня безопасности.

Данный файл необходим для дальнейшего использования в проекте, средой для генерации файла будет использоваться pythonPortable (будет поставляться вместе с проектом), с помощью которого и нужно создать выходной файл.

Answer (score 2):

Запустить скрипт командой

```
python script.py > file.txt
```

Или в самом скрипте

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
```